# ScheduleWidget.Core Every second week

Tags: .net-core, schedulewidget

I'm trying to convert my NET 4 code to NET Core. I'm using [ScheduleWidget](https://squarewidget.com/schedulewidget/), which is working perfect for this project. I've noticed, that [ScheduleWidget.Core](http://schedulewidget.azurewebsites.net/) doesn't have a [RepeatInterval](https://github.com/jamesstill/ScheduleWidget/blob/0546f6812a8c5b2ee1bc167cd3f2e96642f25a97/ScheduleWidget/ScheduleWidget/ScheduledEvents/Event.cs#L67) as the NET 4 version. Am I missing something, or isn't it possible to define these rules anymore? 
I know that this could be done with `first` and `third` week every month. But this ins't a valid solution, because it won't be every second week then.

Comment: Do you have any new info about this?

Comment: @bazsibazsi I decided to use [iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) instead. Which uses the [RRule-pattern](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/rrule-generator) (ex. used by MS Outlook calendar), which makes recurrences much more dynamic.